# rails vim syntax highlighting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

Please excuse my naivety, I come from a world of Textmate but have decided to give vim rails a shot.

I cannot get my syntax highlighting to work, I'm sure this is probably my setup but I am not vim savvy in knowing how to fix this.

Commands like :Rfind etc. are working.

Anyone care to give me some pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if these commands are OS independent, but take a look at this and see if it helps:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VimHowto#Enable%20Syntax%20Highlighting

Specifically:

If you want to just enable syntax highlighting for a session, you can simply issue a colon command

```
:syn on
```

Syntax highlighting can be turned off by issuing another 'colon' command

```
:syn off
```

To make this permanent everytime you open a file, just add the following line to your vimrc.

```
syntax on
```

Comment: The .vimrc will be located in ~/ (your home directory). cd with no args should take you there. If the file isn't there, create it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a pretty detailed blog post this morning which may have something you're missing: http://zigzag.github.com/2010/02/14/from-textmate-to-vim-for-rails-coders.html